# Python: Get random value from a array dimension

Tags: python, arrays, random, numpy

I am trying to get a random element from an array's single dimension in Python. So in the case below, I would like to retrieve any one of the 5 floats.

```
ar = rand(1, 5)

ar = array([[ 0.29889882,  0.84955019,  0.52989055,  0.57220576,  0.16841406]])
```

I have been able to retrieve a float if there are 5 elements and only one dimension 
`(ar = rand(5, 1)),`

using:

```
ar[randrange(0, p.size)]
```

but how do I get a value from an array from a single dimension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are referring to `numpy.array`, you can use the following:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.array([[ 0.29889882, 0.84955019, 0.52989055, 0.57220576, 0.16841406]])
array([[ 0.29889882,  0.84955019,  0.52989055,  0.57220576,  0.16841406]])
>>> 
>>> 
>>> ar = np.array([[ 0.29889882, 0.84955019, 0.52989055, 0.57220576, 0.16841406]])
>>> ar[:, random.randint(0,4)]
array([ 0.29889882])
>>> ar[:, random.randint(0,4)]
array([ 0.52989055])
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets say this:

```
ar = rand(1, 5)

ar = array([[ 0.29889882, 0.84955019, 0.52989055, 0.57220576, 0.16841406]])

#create a generator object that returns random values from your array

def getGen(array):
    def gen(arr):
        yield arr[:,ramdom.randint(0,(array.size - 1))] #yielding random values
    return gen(array) # returning generator object

genFromArray = getGen(ar) #getting generator
genFromArray() #would return a random value from your array
```